# configure: error: memcache support requires ZLIB.

Tags: php, centos, xampp, memcached

When try to configuring memcache with php in xmapp server by following steps shows error.

#  /opt/lampp/bin/phpize

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

# ./configure --enable-memcache --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

**Show errors:**

> hecking for the location of ZLIB... no checking for the location of
>   zlib... configure: **error: memcache support requires ZLIB**. Use
>   --with-zlib-dir= to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

for debian stretch

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have zlib-devel installed

`yum install zlib-devel`